# Next.js Docker Development Setting

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js

I want to run my **Next.js code using docker**. Here is my code structure

[image]

When I build it, it returns success like this.

[image]

But, when I open it, I get this...

[image]

my docker.compose.yaml file contain this...

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    image: 'app'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    container_name: app-next
    build:
      context: web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - /usr/src/app/.next
```

my Dockerfile contain this...

```
FROM node:12-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json yarn.lock /usr/src/app/
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

my browser console contain this...

[image]

Anyone can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: the issue is with your app, not docker because the app is running and giving you a 404 page.

Comment: I start the project from zero and it's work, but when i try to make /restaurant, it renders 404 page, do you know how to solve it?